# How to do version control with enums

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I'm working on a Revit add-on where I need to assign data fields (with external storage). I cannot foresee how many data fields I will need in the future so I need to plan some version control. I need to have the whole version history so I can later program version processor to upgrade entities made with old version to the latest one.

I need to refer to those fields by name (string) but I thought to use enums because it's easy to pick the desired value from the list while you type.

example:

now:

```
enum BoolFields_v1 { IsPipe, IsSomething }
```

future:

```
enum BoolFields_v2 { IsPipe, IsSomething, IsSomethingElse }
```

However, globally in my code I'd like to refer to one single enum: BoolFields. I hoped I could do something like:

```
public enum BoolFields { get {return BoolFields_v2} }

private enum BoolFields_v1 { IsPipe, IsSomething }
private enum BoolFields_v2 { IsPipe, IsSomething, IsSomethingElse }
```

Well, I know it is not possible like that. Any ideas how could this be achieved?

Comment: There is no easy way to do it. You need to explicitly reference v1 or v2.

Comment: consider using enum classes instead.

Comment: Reminds me of enum`[Flags]` attribute.

Comment: The mapping you're creating here (version to used fields) maybe fits for the current case, but you're going to have to create different solutions for version changes that are not field additions. What happens when a field disappears? Or you redesign the lot? Or you add functions? Enums also can't inherit, so there's no relation between `Enum1.Field1` and `Enum2.Field1` (unless you go by int value). But I don't see any benefit of doing what you're currently doing. Enums are supposed to be "pick one of these values", not "here's a group of values to use at the same time".

Comment: @Flater can you suggest different approach? I plan to have IntFields enum, where there will be "Version" Field - by reading a value from entity I will know if the version is current or outdated, if outdated what is the difference and how to treat it.

Answer (score 4):

I have had similar problems, and I opted for namespaces. The latest version is always in a non-versioned namespace, the older versions are:

```
namespace My.Product
{
    private enum BoolFields { IsPipe, IsSomething, IsSomethingElse }
}

namespace My.Product.V1
{
    private enum BoolFields { IsPipe, IsSomething }
}
```

When you move on to a new version, you can copy the relevant model from the current version and move that into `V2`. Then you can edit the current version without problems.

In this case, adding numbers to your enums will ease conversion the old to the new version.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use preprocessor directives as follow:

```
#define v1

#if v1
    private enum BoolFields { IsPipe, IsSomething }
#elif v2
    private enum BoolFields { IsPipe, IsSomething, IsSomethingElse }
#endif
```

The scope of a symbol that was created by using `#define` is the file in which the symbol was defined. You can also define a project-wide symbol by defining in `Project Properties => Build => Conditional Compilation Symbols` or by a compiler switch with `/debug`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good sample of usage of the flags attribute of enums.

```
[Flags]
public enum Features
{
    None    = 0,
    IsPipe = 1,
    IsSomething = 2,
    IsSomethingElse = 4
}

public class MyProduct
{
    public Features VersionFeatures
    {
        get
        {
            return Features.IsPipe | Features.IsSomethingElse;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example the your code if you instanciate a `MyProduct` class a `(int) myVariable.VersionFeatures` would return `5` and you could check for specific features `myVariable.VersionFeatures.HasFlag(Features.IsSomething)` would return `false`.